# Make TextView "\n" ignore paragraph creation

Tags: android, textview, spannable

I have a string of text like this with few newline control characters.

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\nUt enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.`

When I use `LeadingMarginSpan` on the TextView, it applies after every newline character.

[image: leading margins]

^ This is the result I get from applying a `LeadingMarginSpan`.

[image]

^ And this is the result I'd like to have.

Is there any way to ignore paragraphs in `TextView` so we can just have a normal line break?

Comment: you can use use replace string function and just replace "\n"  to " "

Comment: @Deepak that will not create new paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(inset, 0)` from `0` to the first new line only, so it doesn't apply to the rest of the paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.text.Layout
import android.text.style.LeadingMarginSpan

class OnlyFirstParagraphSpan : LeadingMarginSpan {

    private var firstLine : Boolean = true
    private var margin : Int = 32

    override fun getLeadingMargin(first: Boolean) = margin

    override fun drawLeadingMargin(c: Canvas, p: Paint, x: Int, dir: Int, top: Int, baseline: Int, bottom: Int, text: CharSequence, start: Int, end: Int, first:
    Boolean, l: Layout) {
        if (firstLine) {
            margin = 32
            firstLine = false
        } else {
            margin = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no need for using *LeadingMarginSpan*. You can add "\t" to the fist of your text :

```
val text = "\t" + "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit," +
                " sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore " +
                "magna aliqua.\nUt enim ad minim veniam, " +
                "quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi " +
                "ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
text_view.text = text
```

Comment: Leading margin span gives you the option to set the size of the indentation. The `\t` does not.